# getting blank response from Google safe browsing api

Tags: google-api, postman, safe-browsing, safe-browsing-api

I am using postman to send a post request to the google safe browsing api,but I am getting a blank response in return with status 200 ok

```
https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=AIzaSyCG0_ltenJACSir1moT_4bcK4-ROCq4myc  

{
    "client": 
   {
      "clientId": "yourcompanyname",
      "clientVersion": "1.1"
    },
    "threatInfo": {
      "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
      "platformTypes":    ["IOS","WINDOWS","LINUX","OSX"],
      "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
      "threatEntries": [
        {"url": "http://www.bbc.com/"},
        {"url": "http://www.sustainablesites.org/"},
        {"url": "http://kvsangathan.nic.in/"},
        {"url": "http://www.mca.gov.in/"},
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Format the code correctly!

Comment: I tried running it here https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/safebrowsing/v4/safebrowsing.threatMatches.find API seams to be down.

Comment: Is there is any other method which is similar to google safe browsing for testing, scanning the urls????